# When to use combinate vs when to use combination?

Tags: word-usage, definition, word-meaning

I recently came across

> This method combinates both previous methods.

Which seems to be the same as combines. I've never come across combinate before but this is apparently the definition.

> **Noun** *combinate* (plural *combinates*)
>   The result of a combining of two or more components.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the definition as a noun.  ( *I mixed vinegar and baking soda.  The resulting **combinate** was delicious!* )  This is less common than combination, but I wouldn't be surprised to see it, especially in a scientific paper.

The sample sentence you provided uses it as a verb synonymous with combine.  Dictionaries say that's grammatical, but it is very, very, *very*  uncommon.  (I have never heard it, and ngrams has [vanishingly few examples.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=combined%2C%20%20combinated&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccombined%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccombinated%3B%2Cc0))

Comment: I find it wild that I came across it in official documentation. Interesting...

Comment: **Combinate** might be fine in a scientific paper in a field where it has a specific and known meaning, but probably should not be used in everyday conversation. **Combination** is more natural.

Comment: @Andrew - Agreed.

Comment: I would never use *combinate* **anywhere** except in scientific writing. It's simply not used in everyday speech.

Answer (score 2):

According to Merriam-Webster's dictionary the word "[**combinate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/combinate)" is just a rare word for "[**combine**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/combine)". Its popularity is *Bottom 30% of words*.

Quote from [The Oxford Reference Guide to English Morphology By Laurie Bauer, Rochelle Lieber, Ingo Plag](https://books.google.ru/books?id=EXlYCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA275&lpg=PA275&dq=combinate%20verb&source=bl&ots=WNc7TUZtgH&sig=wHorqXfRxJwNKtHduvPliJA9l5A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqlJ-M7uXUAhXhbZoKHdSXDBwQ6AEIXDAL#v=onepage&q=combinate%20verb&f=false):

> There are quite a few forms of verbs that appear to be back-formations from nouns in *-ation*. COCA gives us examples:
>
> - administrate, allegate, **combinate**, commentate, commutate, ...